# ABP Rename API Route in Controller as a Service

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Using ABP service as controller, a default route as such will be generated for a TaskService get method:
/api/services/app/taskservice/gettask

1. is it by default that the "service" word will also appear for task service like /taskservice in the route instead of just /task? If it's not, what could be wrong in my setup?
2. If it is, how can I remove it?
   Like in controller level, I can have api route as such /api/v1/task/gettask by having data annotation below. Is there something similar in service level (which has module name as well)

   [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, only the following postfixes are removed:

```cs
public static string[] CommonPostfixes = { "AppService", "ApplicationService" };
```

You can do either of these:

1. Name it `TaskAppService`.
2. Configure `ApplicationService.CommonPostfixes` in your module's `PreInitialize` method.

```cs
ApplicationService.CommonPostfixes = new string[] { "Service", "AppService", "ApplicationService" };
```

References:

- [https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/.../ApplicationService.cs#L14](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/a706b7e8f497a4afe2bb746892fd6c010b0875fc/src/Abp/Application/Services/ApplicationService.cs#L14)
- https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2441

Comment: Thanks @aaron. Don't mind if I ask another similar question to you.
Is there a way to remove the /services/ prefix?
I see that it is defined private in https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/a706b7e8f497a4afe2bb746892fd6c010b0875fc/src/Abp.AspNetCore/AspNetCore/Mvc/Conventions/AbpAppServiceConvention.cs

Comment: Please use [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

The service have to named as "AppService" as the postfix instead of just "Service"